# How do i redirect input output to file instead of stdout?

Tags: c#

How can i redirect my input and output to a file?

Example if i execute my program as :-

```
abc.exe < input.txt > output.txt
```

It should read input from input.txt and write output to output.txt

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The answer is in the question, so... what is being asked here?

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft :- I didn't know it can be done in c#. I have Linux little bit and so i was searching for the same thing in C#. Didn't know it is available by default ;).

Comment: Cheng: This question has nothing to do with C#.  This is just how input redirection works, in both Windows and Linux (it's handled by the OS).  See http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you mean this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String s;
            while ((s = Console.In.ReadLine())!= null)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using Console.WriteLine and Console.ReadLine

Answer (score 0):

System.Console.SetIn(TextReader newIn)

System.Console.SetOut(TextWriter newOut)

Would be good if you want to vary outputs during program's run.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a console application with the < and > will redirect input and output. Just use Console.Read or ReadLine and Write, WriteLine etc. in your program.